# Is is safe to use result of side effect in expression inside the same expression?

Tags: c++, c, language-lawyer

Consider the following code:

```
int f(int a, int b, int *c) {
    *c = a + b;
    return *c > 0;
}

void check(int a, int b) {
    int c;
    if(f(a, b, &c) && c < 10) {
        puts("sum is in range [1, 9]");
    }
}
```

If the second part of `&&` is ever evaluated, is `c` guaranteed to hold the value assigned to it by function call `f(a, b, &c)`? Does this behavior changes from C to C++?

Comment: The function call is a sequence point but, nevertheless, you still need to be fired or receive an 'F-' grade.

Comment: I guess it's a matter of personal taste. Many people would say such code is perfectly OK.

Comment: Yes, that's fine. `&&` evaluates left to right.

Comment: @anatolyg many people don't do much debugging.

Comment: My actual code is more like `box_intersect(&box_a, &box_b, &result) && !box_contains(&bigger_box, &result)`, where `box_intersect()` returns true if there is an intersection.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It is safe if a sequence point occurs that controls the order of evaluation.

```
// bad: evaluation order of f() and (c < 10) is not specified by C
if(f(a, b, &c) & c < 10) {
// OK,  left half of && must occur first.
if(f(a, b, &c) && c < 10) {
```

With simple `&&` expressions, there is no C,C++ difference.  With C/C++ the left side is evaluated and the right is evaluated if the left is not false.

Behavior on this point is more complex when in C++, the `&&` operator can be overloaded and then both sides of `&&` are always evaluated.

Comment: `&` and `&&` are different operators anyway. With the same rectification one could use `+` instead of `&`.

Comment: @Olaf Behavior is unspecified not undefined.

Answer (score 4):

Yes the expression will be evaluated from left to right and the value of `c` will be updated accordingly. Execution of the program will step into the function and anything that executes in the function will execute before `c < 10` will.

This behavior shouldn't change from `C` to `C++`

Answer (score 3):

> is `c` guaranteed to hold the value assigned to it by function call `f(a, b, &c)`

Yes. This is pretty clearly expressed in [expr.log.and]:

> The `&&` operator groups left-to-right. The operands are both contextually converted to `bool` (Clause 4).
>   The result is `true` if both operands are `true` and `false` otherwise. Unlike `&`, `&&` guarantees left-to-right
>   evaluation: **the second operand is not evaluated if the first operand is `false`**.
>
> The result is a `bool`. **If the second expression is evaluated, every value computation and side effect associated
>   with the first expression is sequenced before every value computation and side effect associated with the
>   second expression.**

Answer (score 0):

The `&&` operator forces left-to-right evaluation and a introduces a sequence point (as does the function call itself); the LHS is fully evaluated (and all side effects applied) before deciding if the RHS needs to be evaluated at all.

Thus, `if(f(a, b, &c) && c < 10)` will work as you expect; if `c < 10` is evaluated at all, it will be with the value written to `c` by the function `f`.

Having said that, this is not great style.  Just because C and C++ allow certain constructs doesn't mean it's a good idea to use them.  Anyone having to maintain your code would probably appreciate you writing it as

```
if ( f( a, b, &c ) )
{
  if ( c < 10 )
  {
    // do stuff
  }
}
```

instead.

Yes, it takes a bit more space on the page, but the logic is more obvious.

Comment: Not sure if I agree about the style. It is basically similar to `if ( (ptr != NULL) && (ptr->count < 10) )` which is a very common construct.

Comment: @olaf: it's the function call embedded in the expression that makes it so ugly to me - `f` returns a value *and* updates `c` *and` then there's a comparison against `c`.  It's compressing a few too many operations together for my tastes.

Comment: Good point. That hidden side-effect is what gives me a bad feeling, too.